# Firebase Analytics.logEvent() doesn't work, but native event are ok

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

First of all, here are my steps:

- Pod Firebase/Analytics 7.5.0 : OK
- FirebaseApp.configure() in app.delegate : OK

  ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   guard let window = self.window else { return false }

   FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.max)
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
  ```
- Google plist : OK ( tested with anther blank application it does work )
- No env var stored
- Debug mode : OK

I do have firebase's native event as Screen view, session_start etc :

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: screen_view (_vs)
```

but as soon as I send myself an event, nothing in DebugViews ( Xcode + Firebase console )

```
Analytics.logEvent("event", parameters: nil)
```

What did I miss, configuration, conflicts between some pods ?

Regards